# android seekbar drawing problem on orientation change

Tags: android, android-widget, seekbar

when the orientation changes, the seekbar drawing is messed up. See voice call and alarm below:
[image]

Comment: how are you handling your orientation change?

Comment: I have a layout-land and layout folder for my layouts. Is there any sort of invalidation i need to do?

Comment: zsniper: Did you ever figure out the reason for this problem. I am having a similar issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Boris Sorry, not yet. I've decided to let this one go due to the obscurity of when this will happen. Unless the seekbars are the main focus of the app (this volume control is only a part of mine), I don't think anyone will notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. `SeekBar.setSaveEnabled(false)` seems to fix this.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look! is there a xml equvalent as well?

Comment: I finally got the time to take a look and your code worked like magic! For everyone else, the xml equivalent is android:saveEnabled="false"

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue myself, and saveEnabled="false" did not fix it.  My problem was that I was calling setMax after setProgress:

`mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMediaDC);

        mSeekBar.setProgress((int) currentItem.volumeDC);

        mSeekBar.setMax(10);`

And changing it to this fixed it:

`mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMediaDC);

        mSeekBar.setMax(10);

        mSeekBar.setProgress((int) currentItem.volumeDC);`